# How can I finish pyspark unit tests gracefully withou `py4j.java_gateway:Error`?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, gateway, py4j

How can I finish pyspark unit tests gracefully without see this annoying error when the test ends? It seems like the python client is losing communication with the spark context or something like that.

> ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:Error while sending or receiving. Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line
>   826, in send_command ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   INFO:root:Exception while sending command.

Comment: could you please paste the code which is causing issue? I am testing with setup and teardown methods

Comment: I am testing with setup and teardown methods 

`class TestPySpark:
    _spark_session = None`

   `def setup_method(self):
        self._spark_session = original_module.get_spark_session()`

    `def teardown_method(self):
        self._spark_session.stop()`.   `def get_spark_session(master_name='local'):
    spark_config = SparkConf().setAppName('PySparkShell') \
        .setMaster(master_name)
    spark_context = SparkContext(conf=spark_config)
    return SparkSession(spark_context)`